# JavaScript Regex, match P but not PARAM

Tags: javascript, regex

Using JavaScript RegEx.

How can I match a `<p>` element(including attributes), but not `<param>` or other HTML elements starting with a "P".

Comment: Why are you manipulating HTML with regular expressions when you've got access to the DOM?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
/(<p(?:\s+[^>]*)?>)/i

/
 (        #start capture group
  <p       #match '<p'
  (?:      #start non-capture group
    \s+     #match one or more white space characters
    [^>]*   #match zero or more characters that arent >
  )?       #end non-capture group - make it optional
  >        #match '>'
 )        #end capture group
/i        #end regexp - make case insensitive
```

Comment: The problem is, that this doesn't match a simple `<p>`. -1

Comment: I noticed that too - and fixed it ;)

Comment: Yup, reverted the -1. +1 for comments.

Comment: Same as Doldewyn, reverted +1 =)

Answer (score 2):

```
/<p\b[^>]*>/i
```

`\b` matches a word boundary; coming after the 'p' it means the next character (if there is a next character) is not a letter, digit or underscore.

Disclosure: `[^>]*` isn't really the correct way to match the rest of the tag, since attribute values can legally contain angle brackets.  But it's probably good enough, and that's not what the question is about anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`<(p|P)([\s].*)?>`

seems to work good =). But you shouldn't use RegEx when you can use DOM, or even XML/XPath/whatever.

Comment: the `.*` in your regexp will be greedy and continue matching beyond the end of the tag, up until the last available `>`.  `[^>]*` or even `.*?` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try:

```
/\<P(\s+\w+=\"?[^\"\s\>]*\"?)*\>/gi
```

Answer (score -1):

```
/<(?:p|P)\s+/.exec(s);
```

Although it doesn't match the entire tag, but that's quite complicated considering that the tag closing symbol > is allowed inside an attribute.

Comment: Right, to avoid that, replace "<" by "&lt;", etc.

Comment: Same as gnarf's answer. Doesn't match a plain `<p>`.

Comment: @Clement: How would you do this. Consider <p title="Greater than (>)">. How would you match the entire tag with a regular expression? (I realize it's possible, that's why I said "quite comlicated", not "impossible").